# Intellisense in jEdit

Tags: java, jedit

Does anyone know of a plug-in that provides intellisense for jEdit?  [This post](http://community.jedit.org/?q=node/view/4279) seems to indicate something exists, but I'm not sure how to get it working on my system.  For now, I'm mainly interested in Java.

Comment: Please don't forget to insert an answer or add your own if you choose another solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

IntelliSense is the name, Microsoft gave their implementation of [autocompletion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocompletion). So you will have no IntelliSense for jEdit (as Microsoft does not provide plugins for jEdit), but you have some implementations for autocompletion:

- [JavaSideKick](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?JavaSideKick): provides autocompletion for Java (and some other helps)
- [SideKick](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?SideKick): general framework for coding-helpers, used by JavaSideKick
- TextAutocomplete: as recommended by Ross Rogers will provide autocompletion using words in the same buffer
- [Completion](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?Completion): general Code-Completion ülugin

Plugins can be easily installed through the plugin-manager.

Answer (score 2):

JEdit doesn't support intelli-sense out of the box.  There are plugins, but I'm not sure of their efficacy nor whether one is available for Java.

One thing it does have out of the box, that is better than a kick in the teeth, is auto-complete based on the words that are in all the open buffers.  The feature is called "Complete Word" and the default key-binding to complete a word is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd>.  This feature is documented [here](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/words.html).

There is a tweaked version with plugin [TextAutocomplete](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?TextAutocomplete).

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CtagsInterface](http://plugins.jedit.org/plugins/?CtagsInterface) too. Does a similar job to the others using Ctags and is nicer I think: can be configured to search for functions/variables in the current project or project + dependencies rather than just open buffers. Also has a preview and suggests full signatures if available.